# React-pdf - download pdf on button click

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to generate and download PDF when specific button on page is clicked, what is important is that i have to perform other instruction when button is clicked.

for creating PDF i'm using [`React-pdf`](https://react-pdf.org/)

I was trying with `PDFDownloadLink` but i cannot find if there is a way to inject validation before download starts.

my PDF look something like this

```js
const MyDoc = () => (
    <Document>
        <Page>
            <View>
                <Text>Hello World!</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
                <Text>We're inside a PDF!</Text>
            </View>
        </Page>
    </Document>
);
```

and download is performed with

```js
<PDFDownloadLink document={<MyDoc />} fileName="xyz.pdf">
    {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download now!')}
</PDFDownloadLink>
```

but as I said, I want to perform actions before downloading begins but I don't need to interfere into pdf content

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a workaroud using [`file-saver` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

my button:

```html
<button onClick={this.submitForm}>Send</button>
```

and `submitForm` method:

```js
submitForm = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload
    const blob = await pdf(
        <MyDoc />
    ).toBlob();

    saveAs(blob, 'wycena.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the 'Download now' string with

```
 <Button> Print </Button>
```

and it will work perfectly fine for you.